# Java Lambda Expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

I am currently learning lambda expressions on JDK 1.8. I have come across some code I have found that I do not understand.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.Comparable;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {

        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
        sort(list, Comparable::<String>compareTo);

    }

    interface MyComparable {
        public <T extends Comparable<T>> int compare(T obj1, T obj2 );
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(List<T> list, MyComparable comp) {

        int n = comp.compare("5","2");
        System.out.println(n);
    }

}
```

`comp.compare("5", "3")` eventually executes `"5".compareTo("2")`.
My understanding was the compiler needs to find a static method with same signature as

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>> int compare(T obj1, T obj2 );
```

I have created such a method and it works. I do not understand why the java compiler calls `"5".compareTo("2")`. Their method signitures are not the same.

Any information as to why the compiler generates this kind of code?

Comment: I debugged the code, and a class of type App$$Lambda$1 was created.

Comment: What is your `sort()` method stands for?

Comment: The name "sort()" does not matter much. I choose any method name to learn and understand lamdas and method references. You could replace the method name "sort" with anything you want. The main question is why the line int n = comp.compare("5","2") works.

Comment: It is really bad style do declare main as throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are trying to learn method references, you should resort to some sort of learning material, e.g. [Oracle’s Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). There you find:

> #### Kinds of method references
>
> | Kind | Example |
> | --- | --- |
> | Reference to a static method | `ContainingClass::staticMethodName` |
> | Reference to an instance method of a particular object | `containingObject::instanceMethodName` |
> | Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type | `ContainingType::methodName` |
> | Reference to a constructor | `ClassName::new` |

So you see, method references are not restricted to `static` methods.

Your method reference `Comparable::<String>compareTo` matches the kind “Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type”.

At this point it’s worth noting that you are actually referencing the method `Comparable.compareTo` as if you had written `Comparable::compareTo`. Since the referenced method has no type parameters on its own, your type argument has no effect. E.g. you could write `Comparable::<Button>compareTo` with the same result.

The referenced method has the functional signature `(Comparable,Comparable) → int` as it consumes two `Comparable`s when invoking `Comparable.compareTo` on one `Comparable`, passing the second `Comparable` as argument (and it will return an `int`). This matches the functional signature of your `interface`

```
interface MyComparable {
    public <T extends Comparable<T>> int compare(T obj1, T obj2 );
}
```

so the method reference can be used in this context.

I have simplified the functional signatures; actually they are `(T,T)→int` using `<T extends Comparable<T>>`, therefore you can only compare two instances of the *same* concrete `Comparable` implementation using this function.

Answer (score 3):

So you're wondering how a method reference with different signature than expected, can be sent as lambda expression. But they don't need to be fully the same. Basically, only *list of parameters* and *return type* matters:

> A lambda expression can be assigned to a target type T if all of the following conditions hold:
>
> - T is a functional interface type
> - The lambda expression has the same number of parameters as T's method, and those parameters' types are the same
> - Each expression returned by the lambda body is compatible with T's method's return type
> - Each exception thrown by the lambda body is allowed by T's method's throws clause

[from here (section 4)](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Ebriangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-final.html)

List of parameters of your `compare()` (`String`, `String`) can be matched to list of parameters of `String#compareTo()` (`this`, `String`) and their return types are also the same (`int`), so one can be used as lambda when another is expected.