# How is this method reference valid?

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

```
class Dish {
  public int getCalories() {
    return calories;
  }

public static final List<Dish> menu = Arrays.asList(
      new Dish("pork", false, 800, Dish.Type.MEAT),
      new Dish("beef", false, 700, Dish.Type.MEAT),
      new Dish("chicken", false, 400, Dish.Type.MEAT),
      new Dish("french fries", true, 530, Dish.Type.OTHER),
      new Dish("rice", true, 350, Dish.Type.OTHER),
      new Dish("season fruit", true, 120, Dish.Type.OTHER),
      new Dish("pizza", true, 550, Dish.Type.OTHER),
      new Dish("prawns", false, 400, Dish.Type.FISH),
      new Dish("salmon", false, 450, Dish.Type.FISH)
  );
}
```

How is the following `Dish::getCalories` method reference valid when `summingInt` requires a `ToIntFunction`? I am asking because the signature of `getcalories` does not match the signature of `applyAsInt` abstract method of `ToIntFunction`

```
int totalCalories = menu.stream().collect(summingInt(Dish::getCalories));
```

Comment: It takes a Dish and returns an int. An equivalent lambda would be `d -> d.getCalories();`

Comment: I understand that. However, the signature of `getCalories` does not match the signature of `applyAsInt` abstract method in `ToIntFunction`

Comment: @karanmirani Look at method reference to understand how it works when a functional interface is needed.

Comment: More duplicates: [Reference to methods with different parameters in Java8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27754335/2711488), [Java Lambda Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29802633/2711488), …

Answer (score 3):

> I am asking because the signature of `getCalories` does not match the signature of `applyAsInt` abstract method of `ToIntFunction`.

Actually, it does match.

`ToIntFunction<T>` is a *functional interface* since it has the annotation `@FunctionalInterface`.  That means that the signature of `applyAsInt` matches any class<sup>1</sup>, method reference or lambda that provides a method that maps from `<T>` to `int`.

In this case `Dish::getCalories` is mapping a `Dish` to an `int` by calling the `Dish` instance's `getCalories()` method on it:

- The source for the mapping is the instance of `Dish`
- The result of the mapping is the result of calling `getCalories()` on the instance<sup>2</sup>.

(Note: this is an intuitive explanation.  For a technical explanation, refer to the relevant parts of the JLS.)

---

<sup>1 - In the case where an instance of a class is supplied, there can only be one method in the class API that satisfies the *functional interface* requirement.  So, hypothetically, if `Dish` was declared with the `@ToIntFunction<Dish>` annotation, it could not expose two methods that take no arguments and return an `int`.</sup>

<sup>2 - Normal method overriding rules apply.  If the actual object is an instance of a subtype of `Dish`, and it overrode `getCalories()`, then the mapping would call *that* method, not the overridden method.</sup>

Comment: > That means that the signature matches any **class**, method reference or lambda that provides a (single) method that maps from <T> to int.

So if a **class** has other methods ie if **Dish** had other methods, then the _method reference_ would be invalid? Also, **getCalories** takes no argument and returns a **Dish** instance whereas **applyAsInt** takes a **<T>** and returns an **int**

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering why it works. It works because `this` is an implicit first argument to every method of an object. Hence, the signature of `Dish::getCalories` is the same as `applyAsInt` of `ToIntFunction`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Emmm, well, it works here! I'm not sure if there is still something concealed here.

```
import java.util.List;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.summingInt;

import java.util.Arrays;

class Dish {

    public int getCalories() {
        return calories;
    }

    public static final List menu = Arrays.asList(
            new Dish("pork", false, 800, Dish.Type.MEAT),
            new Dish("beef", false, 700, Dish.Type.MEAT),
            new Dish("chicken", false, 400, Dish.Type.MEAT),
            new Dish("french fries", true, 530, Dish.Type.OTHER),
            new Dish("rice", true, 350, Dish.Type.OTHER),
            new Dish("season fruit", true, 120, Dish.Type.OTHER),
            new Dish("pizza", true, 550, Dish.Type.OTHER),
            new Dish("prawns", false, 400, Dish.Type.FISH),
            new Dish("salmon", false, 450, Dish.Type.FISH)
    );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int totalCalories = menu.stream().collect(summingInt(Dish::getCalories));
        System.out.println(totalCalories);
    }

    String name;

    int calories;

    Dish.Type type;

    public Dish(String name, boolean b, int calories, Dish.Type type) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.calories = calories;
        this.type = type;
    }

    enum Type {
        MEAT, FISH, OTHER
    }

}
```